# Swift 3.0 array "contains" argument compiler error

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, closures, swift3

Here is the statement that's causing trouble. This worked perfectly in Swift 2.2 but is not working in 3.0 and Xcode 8.

```
  keys = keys
        .enumerated()
        .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.index) }        
        .map { $0.element }
```

Right at `$0.index` xCode is throwing a compiler error:

`Value of tuple type '(offset: Int, element: Any)' has no member 'index'`

As far as I know $0 represents objects in the `keys` array. What tuple is it talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index` has been changed to `offset` in Swift 3 (don't ask me why):

```
keys = keys
    .enumerated()
    .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
    .map { $0.element }
```

Comment: Thank you. It would have been awfully nice something would have indicated this.

Comment: The reason it was renamed is that `enumerated()` doesn't provide you with indices – it simply provides you with a consecutive count from 0. In the case of `Array`, this just happens to correspond with the indices, but this isn't always the case with other collections. Therefore renaming it to `offset` removes this confusion.